# how to make a ridge regression octave

Tags: regression, octave

i have octave 4.2.0 and knew that it dont have this function implemented. I try to make a code, but it dosnt work. Can you please help me to fix it or are there ready codes, which i can use?

My code at the moment:

```
matrix=xlsread('path'); %predictors
Y=xlsread('path');      
[K,J]=size(matrix); 
mid=mean(matrix);      
standard=std(matrix);
Jn=J-1; 
for len= 1:K
for ll=1:J
Z(len,ll)=matrix(len,ll)-mid(ll))/standard(ll);
end
end

I=eye(J,J);
n=1;

for kfact=0:0.0001:0.5

teta(n,:)=inv(matrix'*matrix+kfakt*I)*matrix'*Y;
k(n)=kfakt;
n=n+1;
end
```

Have someone an idea, because i cant find how to make it?

I try to specify my problem. In the book are the values of the parameters, which are calculate in the dependece of k ver small (e.g. 0.02). I get Values, which are about 20. I dont understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work here? What are values of `matrix` and `Y`?

Comment: At the end I want to get the ridge trace to evaluate the predictors of the regression.

Comment: I dont know what i get wrong, but my results dont match with the example from the book. Here are the values: http://www1.aucegypt.edu/faculty/hadi/RABE5/Data5/P320-1.txt